# Why does this route not work?

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-routing

On the class I have:

```
[Route("api/candidate/free")]
```

On the method, I have:

```
[HttpDelete("{dateRangeId}")]
public IActionResult Delete(int dateRangeId)
```

This results in a 404:

```
/api/candidate/free/123
```

When the attribute is removed:

```
[HttpDelete]
public IActionResult Delete()
```

This doesn't result in a 404:

> /api/candidate/free/

What is wrong with the parameter?

Comment: this is most likely because the method for your request is set to "GET". Provide an example of how you are actually trying to access that method (e.g Postman call or HTML form).

Comment: If that was the case, then why would the non parameter version work?

Comment: "off topic" lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That'll do me...

```
[HttpPost("delete")]
public IActionResult Delete([FromQuery] int dateRangeId)
```

Comment: Did you have the from query attribute there all the time?

Comment: No, there was nothing there.

Comment: Isn't that completely different route? In question it's DELETE verb, here it's GET.

Comment: I've changed it to POST - Post to a route that ends with "delete".

Answer (score 0):

The route constraint is case sensitive. You have `Int` when it should be `int`

The action should also follow the expected route template with constraint for it to match the request otherwise you will get *404 (Not Found)*

```
[Route("api/candidate/free")]
public class MyController : Controller {

    //...

    //DELETE api/candidate/free/123
    [HttpDelete("{dateRangeId:int}")]
    public IActionResult MyAction(int dateRangeId) {

        //...

        return Ok();
    }

}
```

Reference [Routing to Controller Actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing)

Reference [Routing in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing)

Comment: That’s what I thought but it was originally int and I changed it because another method that works had Int.

Comment: @IanWarburton Update your question with that detail. You may be having a route conflict, but we wont be able to tell from the limited information you provided. Show the controller and its actions. Also show how you are making the request

Comment: I deleted the constraint because it doesn’t work without it either.

Comment: @IanWarburton you are showing the attributes but not showing the action. We need to see both together to be able to assess why they are not working as expected. For example in my answer I showed how the routing attributes and actions should work together, but that is an assumption given the lack of concrete details in your original question.

Comment: Fair enough. Although how can it be a route conflict if it's a 404?

Comment: Have added the method signature. It was ridiculous not adding that.